# Глаголы без инфинитива

Tags: глаголы

Есть ли в русском языке глаголы, у которых нет начальной формы (инфинитива)? Всем известны глаголы, у которых отсутствует та или иная форма, а вот есть ли такие, у которых нет именно начальной?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Глаголы, не имеющие начальной формы**

Невозможно образовать форму инфинитива от безличного глагола *неймется*.

Не имеют начальной формы:

• глаголы, изменившие свое лексическое значение и поэтому утратившие связь с инфинитивом. Так, например, безличные глаголы *приходится* и *следует* приобрели значения, отличные от значений инфинитивов *приходиться* и *следовать*, с которым они могут быть сопоставлены, и утратили с ними смысловую связь, сравните: Он приходится (личный глагол, инфинитив – приходиться) мне сватом. – Мне приходится (инфинитив отсутствует) с ним общаться. Следуйте за мной. – Тебе следует поторопиться;

• глаголы, инфинитив которых не употребляется в речи, например, *гнетёт* (Меня это гнетёт).

Среди глаголов, начальная форма которых крайне редко употребляется в речи, преобладают безличные (*дождит*, *завьюжило*). В то же время от всех таких глаголов, за редким исключением (*неймется*), можно образовать инфинитив по аналогии с другими глаголами: надлежит/надлежало – надлежать (как лежать), поэтому в словарях можно встретить искусственно образованные, не употребляемые в речи формы инфинитива.

Слово *нет* передает значение изъявительного наклонения и настоящего времени, и поэтому должно рассматриваться как глагол. Это особый неизменяемый глагол, у которого есть только одна эта форма, начальной формы он не имеет.

Источник: Учеба-Легко.РФ [Глаголы, не имеющие начальной формы](http://uclg.ru/education/russkiy_yazik/6_klass/morfologiya/glagol/lecture_glagolyi__ne_imeyuschie_nachalnoy_formyi.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Есть ли в русском языке глаголы, у которых нет начальной формы
>   (инфинитива)?

**Есть.**

См.:

***[неймёт](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D1%91%D1%82), [неймётся](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F), [неможется](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F&all=x), [успеется](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F)…***